# Can't import DATABASE into AndroidProject

Tags: sqlite, import

I created an assets forder in my project, after that i copied my database.sql file into assets.
I have a SQLiteDBHelper.java , but i can't copy that database file into /data/data/ .i think someone can help me.

this is my SQLiteDBHelper.java

```
package com.ngo.evan.testmap;

private final Context myContext;

public SQLiteDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
}
```

}

How can i fix it?